# PageResult always returns null in IAsyncPageFilter - OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync in Asp.Net Core 2.0 Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using a ModelValidationFilter to handle model validation errors for all my post or put requests. I'm using IAsyncPageFilter and registering as a global filter. In the OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync method, I'm able to handle the validation errors for ajax requests and send back a json response. But for non ajax request,

**I'm getting always null for var result = (PageResult)context.Result;**

Please could you assist me on this?

> **I'm implementing this so that I don't need to write model validation in all post or put handlers in any razor page in my application.**

Here is my implementation:

```
if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("POST") || context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("PUT"))
{
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var errorModel = context.ModelState.Keys.Where(x => context.ModelState[x].Errors.Count > 0)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    key = x,
                    errors = context.ModelState[x].Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                });

            context.Result = new JsonResult(new AjaxResultHelper<IEnumerable<object>>
            {
                Response = errorModel,
                Message = "_InvalidData_"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var result = (PageResult)context.Result;

            context.Result = new PageResult
            {
                ViewData = result.ViewData,
                ContentType = result.ContentType,
                StatusCode = 400,
            };
        }
    }
}
else
{
    await next.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: You should just be able to do `context.Result = new PageResult();`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: what about the `ViewData` and `ContentType` that needs to be passed to the `PageResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

> **OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync** : Called asynchronously ***before the handler method is invoked***, after model binding is complete.

Which means that you don't have the **Result** available until after the OnGet/OnPost handlers are called. What you need to do is to get the underlying `HandlerInstance` from the context and cast it as a `PageModel`. You would now be able to access the `ViewData` and `ContentType`.

Then create your PageResult like below:

```
var result = context.HandlerInstance as PageModel;
context.Result = new PageResult
{
    ViewData = result.ViewData,
    ContentType = result.Request.ContentType,
    StatusCode = 400,
};
```

Perhaps return the `BadRequestObjectResult` if the `ModelState` is invalid.

```
if (context.HandlerInstance is PageModel result) //using pattern matching
{
    result.Response.StatusCode = 400;
    context.Result = result.Page();
}

await Task.CompletedTask;
```

The reason you were getting the `site can't be reached` error as there was no Page set when creating the `PageResult`. Instead, you can set the `Response.StatusCode = 400` then call the `result.Page()` that will return the `PageResult`. I have tested the above code and it works.  I hope that helps.

Comment: This returns site can't be reached error. The idea is to avoid model state checking in each handler. Now model state is invalid and the control enters else part as it is not a ajax request and then Site can't be reached error. :( Please assist

Comment: That is strange, can you please upload the sample to GitHub?

Comment: Here is the link to the Repository [ModelValidation](https://github.com/fingers10/ModelValidation). Please check and share your views

Comment: @Abdul Sorry for the late reply. I have edited my answer with the explanation. It should now work. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: No need to feel sorry. Bravo you have made it. I tested and it works fine. Thanks for the teaching and answer. I just curious on how you are learning and finding these solutions? You have a great knowledge. Please teach me

Comment: This approach is fine but got struck with another issue. If I have a dropdown in the page and if model validation fails, the page is now displayed with errors properly but the dropdown values become empty. Is there any way to solve this? I have updated my repo with the new code. Dropdown alone loses its state. Please can you check?

Comment: @Abdul my schedule is quite busy at the moment. I'll get back to you on this as soon as possible. Regarding the learning, I'll give you some tips as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your situation. I'll wait to get the knowledge

Comment: @Abdul Sorry, I still haven't had a chance to look into the issue. I'll try probably tonight if you haven't solved it already.

Comment: @fingers10 Hello, just wanted to check if you managed to find the answer to the Dropdown state problem? I am really sorry that I couldn't come back to you due to my schedule, which is now free. So I can now help. Please let me know if you have more questions. I'll look into the above as well if it's still not solved

Comment: Yeah it didn't get solved. Please can you have a look?