# Error when assigning value to ViewData in PageFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm working on a PageFilter, that I can call on each page to get some data for my _Layout page:

```
public class GetEventFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;

    public GetEventFilter(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {

        if (context.HandlerInstance is PageModel result)
        {

            //result.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            context.Result = result.Page();

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

            var thisEvent = await _context.Events.Include(x => x.AdminCompany).Where(x => x.Domain == context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host && x.Status == 1 && x.ActiveFromDateTime <= dt && x.ActiveToDateTime > dt).OrderBy(x => x.ActiveFromDateTime).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (thisEvent != null)
            {
                if (thisEvent.Logo != null)
                {
                    result.ViewData["Site_EventLogo"] = "/data/" + thisEvent.AdminCompany.Id + "/" + thisEvent.Id + "/media/" + thisEvent.Logo;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.ViewData["Site_EventLogo"] = "/data/" + thisEvent.AdminCompany.Id + "/_system/media/" + thisEvent.AdminCompany.Logo;
                }
                result.ViewData["Site_EventId"] = thisEvent.Id.ToString();
                result.ViewData["Site_EventName"] = thisEvent.Name;
                result.ViewData["Site_EventDomain"] = thisEvent.Domain;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyId"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.Id;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyName"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.Name;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyAddress"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.Address;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyPostalCode"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.PostalCode;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyCity"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.City;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyPhone"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.Phone;
                result.ViewData["Site_CompanyEmail"] = thisEvent.AdminCompany.Email;
                //await next.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/error/404");
            }

        }

    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context) => await Task.CompletedTask;

}
```

My problem is that when I assign values to the ViewData object I get an `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`-error.

How can I fix that? I do know what a NullReferenceException is, I just don't know why I get it in this example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks, @RahulSharma. I know what a NullReferenceException is, I just don't know why I get it in this example.

Comment: This link has the explanation of your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984956/pageresult-always-returns-null-in-iasyncpagefilter-onpagehandlerexecutionasync

Comment: I've found that too, and it seems to get me somewhere. The problem is, when I implement that, the code in the handler is not executed/returned to the view? Please see updated question.

Comment: In your question are your invoking your Task: `await next.Invoke();`. I can see it is commented out

Comment: Yes. Otherwise I got the error `If an IAsyncPageFilter provides a result value by setting the Result property of PageHandlerExecutingContext to a non-null value, then it cannot call the next filter by invoking PageHandlerExecutionDelegate`. Comment out `context.Result = result.Page();`and enabling `await next.Invoke();`did it. Thank you! Please post an answer.

Comment: Did you add a break point and checked which/what is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion on this problem, the first step was to figure out why the `PageResult` was always returning `null`. The answer to this was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984956/pageresult-always-returns-null-in-iasyncpagefilter-onpagehandlerexecutionasync). After resolving the first issue, it was found that on invoking `await next.Invoke();`, the following error was encountered: `If an IAsyncPageFilter provides a result value by setting the Result property of PageHandlerExecutingContext to a non-null value, then it cannot call the next filter by invoking PageHandlerExecutionDelegate`.

To resolve this error, the assignement of the contex result: `context.Result = result.Page();` was removed and then the task was invoked again which resolved the entire issue.

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. A little side question, if you don’t mind: is PageFilter the “correct” way to get me what I want in this case? Previously I was looking at a BasePageModel, but I was not able to make it save ViewData. Maybe it’s just the name “Filter” that makes me think of something else.

Comment: @Mads The `PageFilter` way is correct in your case since you are accessing the `HttpContext`. `Filters` differ from `Middleware` in that they provide access to the HttpContext. One of the things that you might want to do in a filter is to obtain data from an external resource (database, web service etc) and then use it in the PageModel or ViewData which is what you are doing.